# Non-english characters in ASP.NET's Core View are being displayed as �

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have trouble with displaying non-english letters like:

`<h3>żąćń</h3>` because it displays as ����

I tried to add

- `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">`
- `<meta charset="ISO-8859-2">`
- `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`
- `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2">`
- `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

to `head` section in page's layout and it is there in html source code view.

Also:

```
        services.Configure<WebEncoderOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.TextEncoderSettings = new TextEncoderSettings(UnicodeRanges.All);
        });
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Have you tried the page on other browsers?

Comment: @juunas Just tried on firefox and chrome, but without positive result

Comment: Maybe you need to escape html characters?

Comment: did you try to save your .cshtml with utf8 encoding? VS do not use UTF8 by default

Comment: Which css font do you use ?

Comment: @Kalten default:  * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try looking up to check the file formatting on the actual file (using some software to read/write its content, such as **notepad++**)

Make sure to save it encoded as **UTF8**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the HttpUtility.HtmlEncode method will help you further.

What I think you need to do is encode the html entities.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmlencode